# How can I resolve an error "Makfile: No rule to make target"?

Tags: c++, makefile, vagrant, modeling

I am working with an ecological model PEAT-DOS-TEM. I am working in Vagrant ubuntu/trusty64 on a PC. The code I got from GitHub has a Makefile. When i run the command "make" I get this error as a result:

> "make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/TEM.o', needed by 'dos-tem'.  Stop."

I didn't write this makefile and I don't know C++ very well, if you know how to help me please explain as you would to a beginner. Thank you.

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++


CFLAGS= -c -Wall -ansi -O0 -g -fPIC 

LIBS=-lnetcdf_c++ -lnetcdf 
LIBDIR=-Lnetcdf/libs
INCLUDES=-Inetcdf/includes
SOURCES= src/TEM.o \
         src/atmosphere/AtmosUtil.o \

OBJECTS= TEM.o\
        AtmosUtil.o \

GIT_SHA := $(shell git describe --abbrev=6 --dirty --always --tags)
TEMOBJ= obj/TEM.o
    

dos-tem: $(SOURCES) $(TEMOBJ)
    $(CC) -o peat-dos-tem $(OBJECTS) $(TEMOBJ) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)

lib: $(SOURCES) 
    $(CC) -o libDOSTEM.so -shared $(INCLUDES) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)

.cpp.o:  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) DVMDOSTEM TEM.o libDOSTEM.so* *~
```

Comment: its is straight forward error: where is this being `obj/TEM.o` being created? I do not see it. May be you copied incomplete Makefile.

Comment: all the .o files are in the main folder where the Makefile is; all the .cpp files are under a different folder. Do you know how I would edit the Makefile to direct where the obj/TEM.o gets created?

Answer (score 1):

You have asked `make` to build a file `obj/TEM.o`:

```
TEMOBJ= obj/TEM.o

dos-tem: $(SOURCES) $(TEMOBJ)
```

(why do you list `$(SOURCES)` as a prerequisite?) but you have no rule to build that file.  This rule:

```
.cpp.o:  
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<
```

will tell make how to build a file `X.o` from a file `X.cpp`; in your case the `X` is `obj/TEM` so this rule only works if make can find (or build) a file named `obj/TEM.cpp` which it can't.

Comment: Thank you! Currently, both those files exist, but `X.o` is in the main folder and `X.cpp` is in a sub folder. Do you know how I can edit the makefile to tell make how to link these two?

Comment: I understand that one is in a subfolder.  But for make, `X` must equal `X`.  `X` cannot equal "`X`, but in some other directory somewhere with some other name that you have to go searching through the disk for".  There is no way to create a suffix rule (the style of `.X.Y`) where the target and prerequisite live in different directories.  You have to use a pattern rule (e.g. `obj/%.o : src/%.cpp`) where you can specify different directories for target and prerequisite.

Comment: I edited the makefile `.cpp.o:  
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< obj/TEM.o : src/TEM.cpp` and am now getting a different error. Was that the correct way to edit this? I really don't understand makefiles

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure since comments cannot be properly formatted, and you didn't say what the "different error" you're getting is.  The change you made (as best as I can tell) will work, if you have only one source file `TEM.cpp`.  Of course it won't build any other source files.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out the Vagrant box I was using just needed to be updated. The original code is working. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

First check if you have installed c++ compiler by typing g++ in terminal.

Than to compile type in terminal: gcc sourcefile_name.cpp -o outputfile.exe

Finally, to run the code, type: outputfile.exe

Hope it helped

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! I did that and got another error `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`